# Executing $true statement when $false

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-3.0

I am having a bit of trouble with a PowerShell script. The intent of this is to spider the network and look for files/folders that exist on any PC.

Here is the original source:

```
#FiToFin Script#
$Fltr = "how_recover*.*"
$Online = "C:\Users\<username>\Scripts\Logs\Online.log"
$CSV = "C:\Users\<username>\Scripts\Devices.csv"
#$Tstpath = test-path "\\$computer\c$"
$Offline = "C:\Users\<username>\Scripts\Logs\Offline.log"
##################################################
$devices = Get-Content "$CSV"
foreach ($computer in $devices) {
  Test-Path "\\$computer\c$" > $Tstpath
  if ($Tstpath -eq $True) {
    ls -Path "\\$computer\c$\users" -Filter $Fltr -Recurse |
      Out-File -Append $Online
  } else {
    Write-Host "$computer is NOT Online" | Out-File -Append $Offline
  }
}
##################################################
Write-Host "_____________________"
Write-Host "Online file = $Online"
Write-Host "Offile file = $Offline"
Write-Host "_____________________"
```

I have changed the `if` statement to `if($Tstpath -eq "True")`, `if ($lastexitcode -eq $true)` and `if($Tstpath -eq $false)` and they all just parse the first `{Do command}` no matter what. They never drop into `else`. Even tried the `Tstpath = Test-Path \\$computer\c$` as a variable and just running that.

When it parses the first `{Do Command}` the return is

```
ls : Cannot find path '\\<computerName>\c$\u' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\<username>\Scripts\FiToFin.ps1:19 char:3
+         ls -Path "\\$computer\c$\users" -Filter $Fltr -Recurse | Out-File -Append $On ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\<computername>\c$\u:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

What does work:

If my test machines are on I can `ls -Path "\\$computer\c$\users" -Filter $Fltr -Recurse | Out-File -Append $Online` just fine.

I get `True` or `False` from `Test-Path \\$computer\c$` and can even `> $var` and `Write-Host` the results just fine.

I have no idea why this is and would love to know.

This also works:

```
###################################################################
$computer = "TestPC"
$Tstpath = Test-Path \\$computer\c$
####################################################################
$Tstpath > $null
if($Tstpath -eq $True) {
    Write-Host "$computer is Online"
} else {
    Write-Host "$computer is NOT Online"
}
```

But when you add the command `ls` or `Get-ChildItem` it freaks out.
So, question is: Why is it never executing the `else` portion?

Comment: Why bother saving the result? You have a couple of processing issues but mainly the value of `$Tstpath` is never changing. `if(test-path "\\$computer\c$"){}`

Comment: Saving the result allows be to see where a file is on ~2k machines. Why is it not changing? The bottom works beautifully, but when you put in the `ls` on `$true` it immediate brakes.

Comment: I meant the result of `test-path`. If your if succeeds then you know it passed or not. I am helping you by skipping some redundant logic. Just put the test in the `if`

Comment: You are using the redirection operator wrong. `test-path "\\$computer\c$" > $Tstpath` is expecting that `$Tstpath` is a file name. `$Tstpath  = Test-path "\\$computer\c$"` would make more sense for that line.

Comment: Oh is see `if(test-path -eq $true){do something}`

Comment: You syntax is still slightly off. Use _my_ example, in _your_ loop, from my first comment. Also cant remember if you should escape the `$` in `c$` since it is not a varaible. Your error is odd: _Cannot find path '\\<computerName>\c$\u'_

Comment: Ok, and as for the escaping..i could never find a decent answer for that. I tried the backtick ` but it didnt seem to help.

Comment: What do you want the positive log to contain? Just full file paths?

Comment: You should not have to escape in that case because of the slash that follows. I'm sure PowerShell is fine with that.

Comment: Positive log contains what `ls` or `get-childitem` spits out. Name, locations, Parent Dir, timestamp etc.

Comment: @Matt Ok, so the `if` example that you gave works. I have positive info in the file and no errors on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues that would be causing your issues. How you initialize and update the variable `$Tstpath`

```
# Presumably Initialize
$Tstpath = test-path "\\$computer\c$"

# Updating in loop
test-path "\\$computer\c$" > $Tstpath
```

I will assume that you are testing in PowerShell ISE and that `$Tstpath` had a $true value at some point.

The issue is that you were *never* updating the variable. Looking at TechNet for [about_redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) you will see that:

> ```
>    Operator  Description               Example  
>    --------  ----------------------    ------------------------------
>    '>'       Sends output to the       Get-Process > Process.txt
>                 specified file.
> ```

Your command was trying to output that to "file". You should have had an error about not being able to find the file or a file somewhere on your system with a  single boolean in it (since it was not an append redirector).

What you should have done to stay with your logic is save the result via assignment.

```
$Tstpath = Test-path "\\$computer\c$"
```

Then you can test that.

However it is redundant since you do not ever need that value again. Would just be easier to put it straight in the if statement.

```
if(test-path "\\$computer\c$"){"Do something"}else{"Fail Trumpet"}
```

I would also suggest using `Export-CSV -Append` since you are dealing with objects. Would make for good structured output.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "\\$computer\c$\users\" -Filter $Fltr -Recurse | Export-CSV -Append $Online -NoTypeInformation
```